# Need a algorithm for this sorting problem !

Tags: algorithm

012@TEST1
524@TEST2
ABC@TEST3
AB@TEST4
53@TEST5
@TEST6

i want to sort the following data such that 
Final output:
Sorted on the basis of data before ‘@’
Numbers should come before alpha

@TEST6
012@TEST1
53@TEST5
524@TEST2
AB@TEST4
ABC@TEST3

i want to implement this in java ...help me out

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"012@TEST1", "524@TEST2","ABC@TEST3" ,"AB@TEST4" ,"53@TEST5","@TEST6"});

    Collections.sort(stringList,new Comparator<String>(){

        public int compare(String s1,String s2){  
            String c1,c2;
            if (s1.split("@").length >1){c1 = s1.split("@")[0]}else{c1 = ""}
            if (s2.split("@").length >1){c2 = s2.split("@")[0]}else{c2 = ""}
            return c1.compare(c2);
        }
});
```

Or something like that, just tweak the compare method

Comment: i am not aable to understand the code please can anyone give some other way out or help me understand the code ..thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a pseudo-code algorithm or an implementation in a specific language (possibly using libraries provided by that platform)?

This example looks like Java using a sort routine from the platform libraries.

Comment: My example is written in Java isn't what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

its a regular alpha-numeral dictionary sort, but `@` first gets priority, because sadly in the `ASCII` table, `@` got stack between and numbers and the big letters. as you can see here:

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

alternately, you can store the data in `double-valued nodes`, that contains the data from the left of the `@` in `node1`, and the data from the right, in `node2`, and use dictionary sort on `node1`